# How to add unit in an attribute of a class using Pydantic basemodel and field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am using Pydantic BaseModel to define an `Apple` class. I want to add `unit` information so that users can check in the API documentation.

I have two thoughts

1. `Apple1` mentions the unit in the `description` of the `Field`.
2. `Apple2` mentions the unit in a dedicated key of the `Field`. (Note that this dedicated key is not actually provided by `Field`.

The resulting API docs generated by `Fastapi` is like the screenshot below.
[image]

In my opinion, I think `Apple2` is a better design, however it is not shown in the API docs.

Do you have a better suggestion? What is the best practice to add the unit? Thanks.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Apple1(BaseModel):
    price: float = Field(
        description="The price of a Fuji apple. Unit is [EUR].",
    )
    weight: float = Field(
        description="The weight of a Fuji apple. Unit is [kg].",
    )


class Apple2(BaseModel):
    price: float = Field(
        description="The price of a Fuji apple.",
        unit="EUR",
    )
    weight: float = Field(
        description="The weight of a Fuji apple.",
        unit="kg",
    )
```

If you would like to check with fastapi docs, you can use this following code

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app import Apple1, Apple2

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/apple1')
def run1(input_data: Apple1):
    return "Apple1"


@app.post('/apple2')
def run2(input_data: Apple2):
    return "Apple2"
```

Comment: Since `unit` isn't a supported argument to `Field`, I'm not sure it'll convey any expected meaning to people reading the docs or the code - I'd go with the first option, that will at least convey something useful to those reading the documentation. Any unknown arguments will be thrown in the `extra` part of the  `Field` definition: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.Field (now known as `json_schema_extra`)